# Rails Html.erb syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I cant seem to identify where the problem is. Please help me.

> /home/masukami/Documents/ATPAnalyzer/app/views/atp_analyzer/admin.html.erb:205: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' ...emplate: "'.freeze; if (label){;@output_buffer.append=(label... ... ^ /home/masukami/Documents/ATPAnalyzer/app/views/atp_analyzer/admin.html.erb:205: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end ...uffer.safe_append=': '.freeze;};@output_buffer.safe_append='... ... ^

Here's the code

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("dashReport").getContext("2d");
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(swirlData, {
    multiTooltipTemplate: "<% if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%> <%= value %>",
    responsive: true,
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    scaleBeginAtZero : true,
```

Comment: what is your code supposed to do? where are `label` and `value` defined?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby doesn't use curly braces for `if` blocks et al, and neither does ERB:

Here's your ERB:

```
<% if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%>
```

Here's what you want:

```
<% if label %><%= label %>: <% end %>
```

Or, more simply:

```
<%= "#{label}: " if label %>
```